# Simplifying $\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x^2+\sqrt{x^3}+x} : \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^5}-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been doing some math problems for my school exam and came across this one, which I did with the help of PhotoMath, but I couldn't understand one part.

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x^2+\sqrt{x^3}+x} : \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^5}-x}$$

This is how I did it:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} : \frac{x-1}{x(x\sqrt{x}-1)}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{x(x\sqrt{x}-1)}{x-1}$$

// We remove the x

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{(x\sqrt{x}-1)}{x-1}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{(x\sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{x(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{x(x\sqrt{x}-1)}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}$$

// We remove $\sqrt{x} + 1$

$$\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{(x\sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

// Now, this is the part I can't understand, so I used the PhotoMath application

$$\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{x}+1)} * \frac{(x\sqrt{x}-1)(x+\sqrt{x}+1)}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

// We cancel $x+\sqrt{x}+1$

$$\frac{1}{1} * \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

$$1 * 1 = 1$$

Now, I am aware of the "*Rule of the cubes"*, but I couldn't see how I would "implement" that here. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can use PhotoMath for your school exam?

Comment: @peterwhy Hi, sorry I didn't write that correctly. I meant I used PhotoMath **to prepare** for an exam.

Comment: $x\sqrt x -1 = \left(\sqrt x\right)^3-1^3$. Then you can apply $a^3-b^3 = (a-b) (a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Comment: Letting $y=\sqrt x$ from the beginning may be helpful too.

Comment: @peterwhy Ok, so $\sqrt{x^2*x} - 1$ is $\sqrt{x^3} $ or $ (\sqrt{x})^3$?

Comment: For positive $x$, $\sqrt{x^3} = \left(\sqrt x\right)^3$.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A known identity is the following:
$$a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$
Substitute $a=\sqrt{x}$ and $b=1$ and you get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x}^3-1 &= (\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}^2+\sqrt{x}+1)\\
\Longrightarrow x\sqrt{x}-1 &= (\sqrt{x}-1)(x+\sqrt{x}+1).
\end{align*}$$